# Creating apps using the same code with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I am getting in to developing multi platform apps with xamarin but need to build one main project with lots of other similar apps using some of the same code and screens. Is there a way to share code between projects or add different targets like in Xcode?

Comment: yes, you can link files in VS solutions and each project can have different targets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If you want to share code between a few apps, you can add "Portable Class Library" to your project. That way allows you to write 100% compatible code across any project. Altho, that limits a number of frameworks that you can use. If you want to use more of them, you can add "Shared Project" to your project. That allows you to use more of platform specific code (for example Xamarin Components), but you will need to write code more consciously, because it may not work across all projects. [You can read more about code sharing here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/code-sharing/)

2) If you want to build app with different targets [follow this instructions](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-studio/projects-and-solutions/#Run_Configuration)